# How to invoke php include statement using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an `index.php` file. My wish is that, when clicking on a button (which is in `index.php`) an AJAX request should load `about.php` and include it inside a `div` tag in `index.php`.

Below is my code. But this is not working:

index.php:

```
<a href=javascript:onClick('about.php')>About</a>
<div id='dynamo'>
   <?php 
       if($_POST){
       $page=$_POST['page'];                   
       include $page;
       }
   ?>
</div>
```

PageSelect.js

```
 function onClick(text){       
 $.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     url:"index.php",
     datastring:'page='+text          
  });     
 }
```

Comment: Make sure that 1. you have included Jquery lib in your script.  2. Also check you have given correct name along with file path in url inside ajax request.

Comment: yes i have checked again, jquery lib is properly referenced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this (with Jquery):

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="click">About</a>
<div id="render"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#click').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "about.php",
            success: function (response) {
                $('#render').html(response);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/unv6wt03/)

Comment: i used your solution, but the problem is that, when i click the about button the function does not get fired. I even put a breakpoint over the  $('#click').click(function () line and clicked the about again. But the debugger did not hit the breakpoint. i double checked the id name under a tag and one that is used in jquery, but in vain... @Michelem

Comment: Are you sure to have the about.php file in the right place? Can you see any error on the debug console of your browser?

Comment: Sorry I missed a `#` in `render` it should be `$('#render').html(response);`

Comment: Yeah about.php is in root directory only. Even then the problem is that the click event in jquery is not getting fired upon

Comment: Even i added an alert statement inside click event handler. But even that alert is not being fired.

Comment: <li class="scroll_btn"><a id="abt" href="#">About</a></li>

Comment: also i used '#abt' in jquery also

Comment: So it should be `$('#abt').click(function () {` is the HTML element present in the DOM or are you creating it after the DOM is loaded?

Comment: Are you sure your Javascript is loaded into the index.php page?

Comment: TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined
 

$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - 79}, 1000);

Comment: So now i removed the document ready handler and it works like charm.

Comment: thanks again. but if you could help on the error above it would be grateful

Comment: Please open a new question with the relative code. Thanks